# Schedule-wise, is it possible to win a Triple Crown in today's Tennis?

Tags: trivia, tennis, grand-slam

[The Triple Crown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Slam_(tennis)#Triple_Crown) is an achievement wherein a player wins the title in Singles, Doubles and Mixed Doubles in a single Grand Slam event.

Given the scheduling of finals matches being so close together in recent years, is it still possible for a player to achieve this feat?

Comment: The schedules being close is only a problem if matches necessarily overlap. Without that, it can only be opinion as to whether the Triple remains impossible.

Comment: @Nij The organisers have flexibility to tweak the schedule if necessary.

Comment: So it's not totally impossible, but there is no way to make a fact-based statement that yes or no, it is or is not still possible.

Comment: I vote to leave open because as written by Philip Kendall the organisation is flexible to schedule the matches, so if a player would take part to all of the draw the matches will be scheduled to give the possibility to play the matches

Answer (score 1):

**Considering *only* the schedule of the matches is it possible to win the Triple Crown**

There are several examples of schedule modified to give the possibility to tennis players to play in two different draw. Is it possible to see from the [Isner-Mahut played in Wimbledon 2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isner%E2%80%93Mahut_match_at_the_2010_Wimbledon_Championships) where both double matches were postponed because of the duration of the single match.

Obiovously it will be necessary to play (and win!) at least two matches on the same day because:

- Single needs to win 7 matches (+ eventually qualification matches)
- Double need to win 6 matches
- Mixed double need to win 6 matches

So the player has to win at least 19 matches in 13 day (here the [official](http://www.wimbledon.com/en_GB/scores/schedule/schedule20.html) and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Wimbledon_Championships) pages for Wimbledon 2016 women single and double final schedule both won by Serena Williams, mixed double final was played the day after)